# Simple Calendar tool

Tags: delphi, calendar, components

I need to put a calendar control in an option. It must fit in a very small place.

The control must show date number, and color by day if we have something schedule.

Must be able to navigate and select:

- Days
- Month
- Years

Should integrate with database, or manual.

Simple, light, fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the JEDI library, there are several Date and Time related controls, and it's free with the sources.

https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl

Answer (score 5):

Try [TMonthCalendar](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TMonthCalendar) and/or [TDateTimePicker](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker), these are Delphi wrapper components over Windows common controls.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say free and so I can recommend the [TMS TPlanner](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmspack.asp?s=plan) components. They have data-aware and non-data-aware calendar and date-picker controls that can have different colours and shapes on different days according to what is scheduled for the day.

I have used these extensively to provide a diary facility in our software to great effect.